# How can I compile new Set() of ES 6 into ES 5 grammar using Babel?

Tags: google-apps-script, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am compiling with Babel for the development of Google App Script.
Because Google App Script does not correspond ES6 grammar.
I like the ES6 set type, so I tried using ES6's `new Set ()` , but it does not transpile and it is left as it is.
How can I transfer to ES5?

The package.json is as follows.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es5-property-mutators": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-googleappsscript": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Set` is polyfillable. Features that can be polyfilled aren't transpiled.

`core-js`, `babel-polyfill` (it uses `core-js` internally) or any other ES6 polyfill can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Moreover, `Set` *cannot* be transpiled. A transpiler cannot catch all uses of the global `Set` variable.

Comment: Thank you! Your comment was very helpful.